# Define a positive variable in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Using Tensorflow, I am trying to optimize the shape parameter of [Weillbull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution). The shape parameter should be always more than zero.

What is a nice way to define a positive variable in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways of doing this:

1. Assuming you have the parameter in a `tf.Variable`, you can use the `constraint` parameter (`get_variable` has it as well). This needs to be a function that basically projects the variable into the allowed space. E.g. you could pass `tf.nn.relu` here, which would map any negative values to 0 should they occur.
2. Probably more elegant: Use an unconstrained variable, but map it to a positive value via a suitable function such as `tf.exp`. E.g. if your variable is `x`, you pass `tf.exp(x)` as the parameter to the Weibull distribution. Then `x` represents the log of the parameter.

Comment: To the second way, I can also use $tf.square(shape) + 1e-6$. Since the parameter cannot be 0, I have to add a very small value (same thing for tf.exp). Correct?

Comment: I suppose that would work a well; I think exp is most often used for these purposes but to be honest I'm not sure why. It might have some deeper reasoning from mathematics/statistics. Nonetheless, any function that maps to positive numbers should be fine. Adding a small constant seems like a good idea for numerical stability (this is less of a concern when using exp since this is always > 0 except for underflow).